# Combining fields with GROUP BY ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to have a query that shows every contract made in my company and have it grouped by function.

My problem is that I have a lot of functions, for instance:

- Partner
- Seller
- Manager
- Captain
- Etc.

I want to show 3 rows, one with all contracts from "Partners", other by all the "Interns" (everyone that isn't a partner), and last one with a Total of the two, achieved with the `ROLLUP`. But I can't seem to only show this 3 rows, my query turns everything that is not partner to be name "intern", but doesn't combine this cells, so I get this result:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Seller Type  |  Installed  |   Scheduled  |  Total  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Intern       |      1      |      0       |    1    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Intern       |      3      |      0       |    3    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Partner      |     10      |      5       |    15   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Intern       |     19      |      10      |    29   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Total        |     33      |      15      |    48   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

And my goal was to Group everyone that isn't a "partner" into the same row, and show it like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Seller Type  |  Installed  |   Scheduled  |  Total  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Partner      |     10      |      5       |    15   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Intern       |     23      |      10      |    33   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| Total        |     33      |      15      |    48   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

My data for table `CM3`

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| u_func       |     cm      |     name     |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Captain      |      1      |     Chris    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Manager      |      2      |     Mary     |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Partner      |      3      |    Anthony   |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| Seller       |      4      |    Hannah    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

My data for table `BO`

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| stamp        |    seller   |      sta     |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| PO109832910  |      1      |   Installed  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| PO389213201  |      2      |   Installed  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| PO930821639  |      3      |   Scheduled  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| PO987583213  |      4      |   Scheduled  |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

My query is

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN GROUPING(CM3.u_func)=1 THEN 'TOTAL'
          WHEN CM3.u_func <> 'Partner' THEN 'Intern'
       END "Seller Type"
, COUNT(CASE 
          WHEN BO.stat = 'Installed' THEN 1 
       END) "Installed"
, COUNT(CASE
          WHEN BO.stat = 'Scheduled' THEN 1
       END) "Scheduled"
, COUNT(CASE
          WHEN BO.stat IN ('Installed','Scheduled') THEN 1
       END) "Total"
FROM BO
JOIN CM3 ON cm3.cm = BO.seller
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CM3.u_func)
```

Comment: What does your data look like *before* you aggregate it? Showing us what your data looks like after your failed attempt won't help us help you unless we do some (guessed) reversed engineering.

Comment: I edited the post and show my data before trying to show only "Interns" and "Partners"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `GROUP BY` to mirror the logic in your `SELECT` statement (which also needs some adjustment):

```
SELECT CASE 
      WHEN GROUPING
      (CASE 
      WHEN CM3.u_func = 'Partner' THEN CM3.u_func 
      ELSE 'Intern'
   END) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL'
   ELSE CASE 
      WHEN CM3.u_func = 'Partner' THEN CM3.u_func 
      ELSE 'Intern'
   END 
   END "Seller Type"
, COUNT(CASE 
      WHEN BO.stat = 'Installed' THEN 1 
   END) "Installed"
, COUNT(CASE
      WHEN BO.stat = 'Scheduled' THEN 1
   END) "Scheduled"
, COUNT(CASE
      WHEN BO.stat IN ('Installed','Scheduled') THEN 1
   END) "Total"
FROM BO
JOIN CM3 ON cm3.cm = BO.seller
GROUP BY CASE 
      WHEN CM3.u_func = 'Partner' THEN CM3.u_func ELSE 'Intern'
   END WITH ROLLUP
```